# Progress Bar With Different Messages For Different Files

Tags: android

I have implemented a progress bar for downloading two files, the progressbar is as follows

```
    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        if (x.equals("xP"))
        {
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        }
        if (x.equals("xV"))
        {
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating file. Please wait...");
        }

        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;       
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

I would like to display a different massage for each of the two files (downloading and updating).

1. I press a button
2. It calls class A (x = xP) which downloads the file (message is Downlaoding)
3. Class A then calls class B (x = xV) which downloads a second file(message is Updating)
4. However x is not known when the progressbar launches
5. If I set x at onClick button then x will remain the same value through the entire button event even though the event launches the two classes with x defined in them and therefore message will always be Downloading for both files. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the message of progressDialog dynamically, so once you get `X` you can set the message to appropriate one.
To avoid confusion, try updating the message in Class A and Class B itself if its running in UI Thread.

Comment: What I have noticed, the progressbar runs twice for each file in a single instance, which is fine however it is called only once and not twice, I have put a system out print which shows that is is called only once but runs twice and that is why i am struggling, it does not start again for each file.

Comment: check for the instance of progress bar, if it is not null and isShowing() is true , just update the message of it, else create a new instance.

Comment: Thank you, I used isShowing() in an If and else statement but for some reason it updates in the else (not if) statement but this works for me:

                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                 System.out.println("SHOWING:");
                    //THIS IS FALSE?
                    }
                else
                 {
                 System.out.println("NOT SHOWING:");
                 pDialog.setMessage("Updating file. Please wait...");
                 }